# How to remove role of a user from particular resource in node_acl?

Tags: node.js, acl

I have multiple resource and multiple user in my project. Single user may have different-2 role on different-2 resource. But the problem with node_acl is, if I want to remove the role of a user from a particular resource there is no any feature(way).

**let me explain this.**

*I have 2 resource let call then "resource A" and  "resource B" and on both resource User "Bharat" have admin role.*

> Allow resource

```
redisAcl.allow([{
    roles: ['admin'],
    allows: [{
        resources: "resources A",
        permissions: "Put"
    }]
},{
    roles: ['admin'],
    allows: [{
        resources: "resources B",
        permissions: "get"
    }]
}]);
```

> Adding user role

```
redisAcl.addUserRoles("Bharat", "Admin", function() {
```

})

*It will set Admin role to "Bharat: on both resource. Ok I will manage this for time being. Because I have a built in method to check permission on any resource.*

> Like

```
  redisAcl.isAllowed("Bharat", "resources A", "get", function(err, allowed) { 
console.log("first",allowed); // result is false})

     redisAcl.isAllowed("Bharat", "resources B", "get", function(err, allowed) {
console.log("first",allowed); // result is true. })
```

But if i want to revoke the admin role from **"Bharat"**. If  I use `removeUserRoles()` method for reworking the admin role  from **"resource B"**.

```
redisAcl.removeUserRoles("Bharat", "admin", function() {

    })
```

it will also revoke the admin role of **"Bharat"** from **"resource A"**.
is there any way to do this or remove("revoke") role of a user from particular resource with node_acl.

I am using [node_acl](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl) module to managing ACL.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat similar issues raised on the Node ACL site around how individual roles are removed.

https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/issues/160